# comparing two text strings in excel to find if they match

Tags: excel, if-statement, exact-match

I have derived a file using two different methods; FoxPro and SQL. Because I am most familiar with it, I decided to compare the two end results in Excel to see if they are identical. 79,954 rows so needless to say, not going to do this line by line. First, I want to see if the company names are the same. I create a new tab and put the company name columns from each next to each other. From there, The first method that I used is

```
 =exact (B2,C2)
```

It returns a false value when I can see with my eyes is not true. Next I use a very simple IF statement,

```
 =if(b2=c2,0,1)
```

It returns a value of 1.

Is there a better method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXACT is case sensitive so you need to be sure you don't have any up/low letter mismatch.

You can also use equal which is NOT case sensitive:

```
=B2=C2
```

This formula will return TRUE or FALSE.

If it's still not working perhaps you have some spaces or other hidden characters. A solution would be to check if B2 includes C2 and opposite.

Comment: I found that there were 18 to 20 extra spaces in the excel sheet that derived from sql. Used a trim function and got reasonable results after that.

Comment: The SQL column is most likely CHAR or NCHAR then, which retains trailing spaces on export, unlike VARCHAR and NVARCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

`=exact (B2,C2)` does work, but you might have a space at the end some of your data which will return a false instead of a true because it compares the 2 and sees that "Test " does not equal "Test" because of the space be there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to hakela's answer, you could TRIM them first:

=(TRIM(B2)=TRIM(C2))